# TableView not scrolling in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UITableView` inside of a `View`. I've dragged the size of the `UITableView` to only displays 4 rows at a time. In the `ViewController` code that loads data into that `UITableView`, I've generated 6 items to load into the `UITableView`, because I wanted to verify that it would scroll.

However, when I run the program and preview it in iOS Simulator, it is not scrolling. I have checked that scrolling is enabled ([Screenshot](http://harlankellaway.com/images/iOS_Issue_TableViewNotScrolling.jpg)).

Here is the code in which the `UITableView` is populated:

```
#import "APFacebookFriendsViewController.h"

@interface APFacebookFriendsViewController ()


@end

@implementation APFacebookFriendsViewController

@synthesize facebookFriendsTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // set View title
    self.title = @"Facebook Friends";

    // load Facebook friends
    self.facebookFriends = [self getFacebookFriends:@"Test Facebook User"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.facebookFriends count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.facebookFriendsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    NSString *facebookFriend = [self.facebookFriends objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:facebookFriend];

    return cell;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getFacebookFriends:(NSString *)facebookUser
{
    // placeholder data
    NSMutableArray *facebookFriendsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend A"];
    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend B"];
    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend C"];
    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend D"];
    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend E"];
    [facebookFriendsArray addObject:@"Friend F"];
    // END placeholder code

    return facebookFriendsArray;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to tell what you're doing wrong without looking at your whole project. A few things that you might want to try:

- Make sure that the table view is on the top of the other views
- Check that table view's `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true.
- Make sure that the table view's delegate and data source points to your view controller.
- Try to make the table view full size and see if it's still not scrolling. If so, probably you didn't set one of the table view properties right. You can try to remove and re add the table view.

There are many more things that can go wrong, and as I said it's pretty hard to tell without seeing your project.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - tried them, still not functional.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check Your table view, and its `superviews`, has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `TRUE`.
2.The custom view that the table view is inside is smaller than the table view with `clipsToBounds=NO`, a subview that beyond the bounds of its parentview and its not interacted with. so set to `clipsToBounds` `YES`.

Comment: I checked that the view and its super view have `userInteractoinEnabled`. The only setting related to `clipToBounds` I found is called *Clip Subviews* - that was enabled for the view and disabled for its super view when I dragged these views into place. I tried checking and unchecking the *Clip Subviews* option, but that did not affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into viewDidLoad;

```
table.delegate=self;
table.datasource=self;
```

Comment: Where would this go and why?

Comment: I've already set the delegate and data source in the Story Board.